# Named JSON array in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, json, django-rest-framework

Actually I've defined model serializer:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name', )
```

which prepare for me JSON reponse in format:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Object One"},
  { "id": 2, "name": "Object Two"}
]
```

How should I modify my serializer class to get JSON response in format:

```
{
  "results":
  [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Object One"},
    { "id": 2, "name": "Object Two"}
  ]
}
```

Do you have any advices or link to django-rest-framework documentation where can I find description to this issue?

Comment: I am not aware if there is possible built-in solution but why don't you create own dict e.g. `results = {"results": json_from_serializer}`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `list()` method [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L73).

Assuming you're not using paginated data (which you question implys) it's essentially just doing this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

So, you just need to override that to use your own custom style instead...

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)
    return Response({'results': serializer.data})
```