# How to change default behavior of serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am doing some stuff with the django restframework. Very basic now, but I like to have my data coming back to me bit differently.

This is how I get the response now:

```
[
    {
        "line": "line1",
        "user_text": "Some text",
        "topic": "value/xrp"
    },
    {
        "line": "line2",
        "user_text": "Some text 2",
        "topic": "beer/heineken/sale"
    }
]
```

This is what I like to get:

```
{
    "line1": {
        "user_text": "Some text",
        "topic": "value/xrp"
    },
    "line2": {
        "user_text": "Some text 2",
        "topic": "beer/heineken/sale"
    }
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
class LineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    line = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
    user_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
    topic = serializers.CharField()
```

This is the view

```
class DisplayDetailAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = LineSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Line.objects.filter(display__serial_number=self.kwargs['serial_number'])
```

And the model (as reference)

```
class Line(models.Model):
    display = models.ForeignKey(Display, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lines')
    line = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    user_text = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.line
```

I looked in the rest framework documentation and a bit here on stackoverflow but I could not find an answer yet.

If someone has hints for me that would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253363/named-json-array-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: @marke Thanks for your reply. The articale however will not help me. It is intended to add a key above on the current response. I like to get rid of the list, and have one of the values of the model on a higher level in the json

Comment: you may need to alter the serializer response

Answer (score 0):

You can override [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) in your serializer class:

```py
class LineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Line
        fields = ('user_text', 'topic')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)

        response_data = {}
        response_data[instance.line] = data

        return response_data
```

You just create a *temporary* data dictionary and assign the current instance `line` attribute to be the key of your JSON response - what you actually want to have in the end:

```
[
    {
        "line1": {
            "user_text": "lorem ipsum",
            "topic": ...
        }
    },
    {
        "line2": {
            "user_text": "dolor sin amet",
            "topic": ...
        }
    }
]
```

---

*Note 1*: You may want to use a `ModelSerializer` instead of `Serializer` in this particular case, I think it is more straightforward to use and you can access `instance.line` directly, without specifying it actually to be serialized.

*Note 2*: Here your `topic` field will be serialized as an `id` since it is a `ForeignKey` relation on a database level. If you want to serialize `topic` as a `CharField` from one of the actual topic's fields, have a look [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).